# in as3 how would you make a fish face the right way

Tags: actionscript-3

without using rotation and adding a different frame. Is there away to make a fish face the right way? this is because i have an animation in it and it would be a big hassle sometimes just to recreate each frame to face the right frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fish.scaleX=-1;
```

Voila, your fish now faces opposite side X-wise. Should it swim downwards instead, shift `scaleY` to -1.

Comment: i just realize that will also flip the textfield lol. but cheers anyway

Comment: yep, textfield too, if it's a child of fish. But you can place fish in one asset, textfield in another, and swap only fish.

Comment: Better off doing fish.scaleX=-fish.scaleX in case it was scaled already you don't want to lose that.